# Minizinc - How can I constrain each column of an array to contain only one of a given integer?

Tags: arrays, constraints, constraint-programming, minizinc

I'm trying to populate a 10 row array such that each column contains a "1",  a "2", a "3" and seven "0" s.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  I tried constraining the column total to equal 6 but that returned columns with six ones, two threes etc.  Is there a 'count' function that I am unaware of?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least three constraints that can be used for this:

- global_cardinality
- count
- and perhaps all_different_except_0

See https://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc-globals.html for a list of the global constraints supported in MiniZinc 2. The counting constraints are here: https://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc-globals-counting.html

An example of how to use global_cardinality is here: http://hakank.org/minizinc/sudoku_pi.mzn

Comment: Good advice ... thanks!  Is it possible to use the `predicate exactly` constraint to achieve the same outcome? I.e: in each column I want exactly 1x3, 1x2, 1x1 and 7x0?   How to I use this predicate in each column of the array:

`array[1..10,1..15] of var 0..3: s;` ?

I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: You can use exactly for this (in about the same way as count). global_cardinality is probably better/faster since it works on the all the number on the same time, i.e. you don't have to use a loop.